# Update, Delete do not work with angular $resource + [php]

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, angular-resource

I'm new to angular js and php both. I found bit limited documentation about using $resource to update recode in db. However I found a good tutorial [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/creating-crud-app-minutes-angulars-resource/) , which gives almost everything about $resource but couple of things that I'm not able to make it work is updating and deleting the record in db using $resource.

my resource service code:

```
var configServices = angular.module("configServices", []);
configServices.factory('Category', ['$resource', function($resource){
 return $resource("/configurator/api/categories/:id", {id:"@category_id"},
{update:{
mothod: 'PUT',
isArray: false
  }
 })

}])
```

Here is my service code:

```
  this.updateCategory = function(_data){
var newUpdate = Category.get({id:_data.category_id}, function(result){
  newUpdate.data = _data;
  newUpdate.$update(function(res){
    console.log("Got respose from update call" + res);

   })
 })
}
```

You can see that I'm pretty much following this tutorial but not able to update or delete record in db. Kind help to figure out, what I'm doing wrong.

php:

```
private function updateCategory($data){

    $_id = implode("", $this->args);
    $query = "UPDATE cg_category SET category_name = '$data[category_name]' WHERE category_id = '$data[category_id]'";

    $result = mysqli_query($this->db, $query) or mysql_error();

    if($result)
    {
        $this->response($this->json(array("Success" => true)), 200);
    }

}
```

Comment: You don't inject the ngResource module. As the tutorial suggests, you should download ngResource module and then inject it, such as: angular.module('configServices',['ngResource']); Then you can use it in your service.

Comment: What errors are shown in your console when you try to update or delete?

Comment: ngResource is injected as dependency in main module and I'm able to query, save and get using ngResource. I'm not getting any error though it's not hitting PUT method (updateCategory) implementation in PHP at all, not sure why.

Comment: Have you tried including an error callback on your update method in angular? Also how do you handle the PUT request in PHP apart from that method you posted?

Comment: Yes, I've tried adding error callback too. It gives success message with old row data as response. I noticed that it doesn't yield as PUT method in php but yielded as GET.

Comment: Does it even call the updateCategory method? Doesn't it rather call the get method and therefore doesn't update the row? Can you show us more of your PHP code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is a bug in Angular $resource class where PUT method also send GET request, So I moved on to use $http put method and that works great.

Here is my final working code with $http

```
this.updateCategory = function(_data){
$http.put("/domain/api/categories/"+_data.category_id, _data).success(function(res){
  console.log("Got put method " + res);]
 })
}
```

However I'd still love to hear from you incase you find $resource class working for PUT method.